# How do I prove that $L = \{a^{i}b^{j}a^{k} | i ≠ j, j ≠ k, k ≠ i ; i, j,k > 0\}$ is not context free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

It's not an assignment question, but I'm trying to prove that $L$ is not context free.
$$
L = \{a^i b^j a^k \mid i \neq j, j \neq k, k \neq i; i, j, k > 0\}
$$

---

Edit:
Thanks for helping me with this thread.
Source: I came across this question in an old exam.
I want to find the solution out of curiosity.
I know a context free language is a language with a CFG. Example: $a^n b^n$
I believe we could use the pumping lemma for context free languages, choosing the word = $a^{n!} b^{(n+1)!} c^{(n+2)!}$ but I couldn't find a good w=uvxyz to prove it! Thank you all.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Generally , MSE has some guidelines. (1) You have give the source of the Question : Here you say that you made up the Question. (2) You have say why you want the Solution : Here it looks like your Curiosity. (3) You have to give your work & thinking : Here , you say you have no clue. (4) With that , this is the minimum you can include in the Post : (4A) Definition you know about "context free" (4B) Proving a very Small Example is "context free" with your Definition. (5) When we know (4A) & (4B) , we can know your level to give Suitable Answers to your Question at your level !

Comment: Is it $a^ib^j\mathbf a^k$ or $a^ib^j\mathbf c^k$ ?